# Electric charges separation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, experimental-physics, charge

I know that any electric charge (Millikan) is always an integer multiple $n\in \Bbb Z$ of the electron charge $e$ i.e.
$$\boxed{Q=ne} \tag 1$$
Assuming by induction or contact or by friction to separate an electric charge $Q$ that has an excess of protons ($6$ to be exact) near two other neutral charges of the same size,

[image]

there is after contact the charge equipartes, obtaining three charges of $Q/3$.

[image]

So from the $(1)$ every charged sphere $q$ is:

$$\boxed{q=\frac n3 e}$$

> **Question**: Is the subdivision by $N$, with $N\in \Bbb N$ charges verified experimentally with a leaf electroscope, or is there a physical law that confirms the subdivision in relation to the number of spheres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had never actually read [Millikan's paper](https://history.aip.org/exhibits/gap/Millikan/Millikan.html) until earlier this year. It is a real tour de force of experimental technique and science communication, and I recommend it highly. But the very short version (expounded upon in the linked answer) is that, because the electronic charge is so small, measuring single-electron charge effects requires you to worry about many nitty-gritty experimental details that ordinary people are free to forget or ignore.  I described some in [an answer to a similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/627146/44126).

The experiment you are describing is almost certainly impossible. (Not the least problem: any three-body interaction is, under the hood, a sequence of two-body interactions.) Let's think about a simpler one: imagine a sphere with charge $Ne$ comes into contact with an identical uncharged sphere, so that the charges should redistribute:

$$
\Big(Ne\Big) + \Big(0\Big) \to \Big(\frac N2e\Big) + \Big( \frac N2 e \Big)
$$

Some issues you'd have to deal with:

1. Suppose that $N$ is odd. Now it's impossible for them to share their charge equally.  One of the spheres is going to have more charge than the other.  You might expect this to happen randomly.
2. For that matter, suppose $N$ is even. Is the random process that distributed an odd number of charges still going to introduce [shot noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_noise) into the partition of charges?  Probably they don't come out even every time in any case.
3. What is the time constant for this charge transfer to happen? Can the contact between the spheres be "too brief"?  Can it be "too long"?  Does the condition of the surfaces matter?
4. How are you producing these "identical" spheres?  Are they actually identical?  Remember that for a Millikan-type experiment, the size scale of interest is "aerosol."
5. Are the sphere's masses changed or unchanged when they interact?  Millikan's aerosols were oil droplets, which would tend to merge rather than exchange charge and separate again.
6. How are you getting the spheres to touch each other? You can't push on them by touching them, because that's an avenue for charge transfer. Perhaps they need to start out with opposite charges?  (I'm pretty sure Millikan's aerosol setup included droplets with both charge signs, but I haven't re-read the paper to check.)

In answer to your block-quoted question: if you are imagining measuring few-electron charges with a leaf electroscope, you have some order-of-magnitude computations to do about the masses and forces involved in that apparatus.

But don't take this response to mean that your proposal is "unverified experimentally."  There is an *enormous* body of evidence that matter consists of nuclei with integer charges, attracting and exchanging electrons with unit charges, and incidental unstable particles with unit charge.  It's possible under special circumstances for these integer-charged particles to interact collectively as [quasiparticles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiparticle) with fractional charge, but (1) even then the fractions are rational numbers, and (2) that's irrelevant for charge transfer between charged objects.  Quantization of charge is one of the most thoroughly verified hypotheses in the history of human science.