# Problem in reanalyzing Millikan's original data

Tags: experimental-physics, charge, measurements, history

I am reading Millikan's original paper "[The Isolation of an Ion, A Precision Measurement of Its Charge, and the Correction of Stokes's Law](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/1634813.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A6f888cba5eef482154bdf7a7759f840c&ab_segments=&origin=&acceptTC=1)" and I am trying to check results of the calculations. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work and I am looking for help, what I did wrong. Take for example "Drop 5" in Table II the first line:

[image]

Then I try to get the value of $e_n = 10.98 \,\mathrm{esu}$ by applying formula (4):

[image]

with the following parameters:

- For $\mu$ (viscosity of air) I used the value from the header of table I (p 439): $\mu = 18,37 \cdot 10^{-6} \, \mathrm{Pa s}$
- $\sigma = 0.9041 \, \mathrm{\frac{g}{cm^3}}$ (density of oil) from the header of table II
- For $\rho$ (density of air) I didn't find a value in the paper itself (maybe I overlooked it). Is there another source to see what Millikan actually used for $\rho$?. So I just used $\rho = 1.1839 \, \mathrm{\frac{kg}{m^3}}$ from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_air) at 25 degree Celsius.
- Also for $g$ I didn't find any value in the paper itself. So I used the value for chicago (where the measurements are taken, as far as I know) which I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth#Comparative_values_worldwide): $g = 9.804 \, \mathrm{\frac{m}{s^2}}$ (maybe historically Millikan used a slightly different value)
- The variable $F$ is used twice in the paper. In the table II it denotes the flight time when the electric field was on. In formula (4) it denotes the electric field strength, I calculated (assuming in good approximation a uniform electric field) just by dividing the potential difference ($V = 9150 \, \mathrm{V}$, from the left of table II) by the plate distance reported on (the end of) page 436 as exactly $16 \, \mathrm{mm}$.
- $v_1$, the speed under gravity (and air drag) I calculated by dividing the distance between the cross hairs ($1.303 cm$) by the value reported in column G (here $120.8 \, \mathrm{s}$; maybe Millikan also used the mean value $120.07 \, \mathrm{s}$ on the left column, I am not sure, both doesn't work).
- Similarly I calculated $v_2$, the speed under influence of the electric field using column F.

I have done the calculations with a little python script shown below:

```
# Millikan 1911

import pandas as pd
from numpy import *
import scipy.constants as co

D = pd.read_csv('Millikan_1911.org', sep='\s*\|\s*',engine='python').iloc[:, 1:-1]

dPlate = 16e-3
g = 9.804
rho = 1.1839  
q_e = 1.602e-19 

mu = 1.837e-5
expr = """
v1 = d*1e-2/G
v2 = d*1e-2/F
E = U/@dPlate
sigma = sigma*1e3
en = 4/3*@pi*(9*@mu/(2*@g*(sigma - @rho)))**(3/2)*sigma*@g/E*(v1+v2)*v1**(1/2)
enESU10 = en/(3.3356e-10)*1e10
n = en/@q_e
"""

D = D.eval(expr)

print(D)
```

where `Millikan_1911.org` contains (in this example I took the mean value for G)

```
| Nr     |     d |    U |    T |  sigma |      G |    F |
| 5 (R1) | 1.303 | 9150 | 24.6 | 0.9041 | 120.07 | 26.2 |
| 5 (R2) | 1.303 | 9150 | 24.6 | 0.9041 | 120.07 | 11.9 |
| 5 (R6) | 1.303 | 9150 | 24.6 | 0.9041 | 120.07 | 67.4 |
```

Executing the script gives this result (E denotes here the electric field, since F was used twice by Millikan):

```
       Nr      d     U     T  sigma       G     F        v1        v2         E            en    enESU10         n
0  5 (R1)  1.303  9150  24.6  904.1  120.07  26.2  0.000109  0.000497  571875.0  3.697707e-19  11.085584  2.308182
1  5 (R2)  1.303  9150  24.6  904.1  120.07  11.9  0.000109  0.001095  571875.0  7.345254e-19  22.020789  4.585053
2  5 (R6)  1.303  9150  24.6  904.1  120.07  67.4  0.000109  0.000193  571875.0  1.842258e-19   5.523019  1.149974
```

So what do I have to change (how and why) to reproduce Millikan's values for $e_n$ exactly?

**Edit** As a response to @rob's comment, here is an overview of the values as calculated by me and that of Millikan (rounded to four significant digits).

```
       Nr    enESU10 (Julia) enESU10 (Millikan)
0  5 (R1)  11.09             10.98
1  5 (R2)  22.02             21.98  
2  5 (R6)   5.523            5.495
```

Comment: Note that in a later paper, Millikan devised a differential measurement where most of these values canceled out. [See this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/627146/44126).

Comment: Your comments on my first answer below leaves me a little confused about just what your question is. I think your concern is that Millikan’s table contains in its first row, the charge 10.98, while your more complicated output table (v2) contains 11.09 in its first row? A summary of what you have computed compared directly to what you are expecting would make your question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In your quoted expression, the air density appears only as a correction to the oil density,

$$
\sigma-\rho = \sigma\cdot\left(
1-\frac\rho\sigma
\right)
$$

Millikan is aiming for about four significant figures of precision.  Since $\frac\rho\sigma≈10^{-3}$, you only need about two significant figures on $\rho$ to get adequate precision in the difference.

The gravitational acceleration $g$ appears in your expression only as a product with the oil density, $\sigma g$ (with the air-density correction in the denominator).  If the droplet has some unknown radius $a$, then $\sigma g a^3$ is just proportional to the weight of the droplet.
I haven’t read the 1910 paper in your question as carefully as [I’ve read the 1913 paper](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/627146/44126).
I think  what’s happening in your quoted expression is that Millikan is trying to get rid of the unknown diameter, in order to account for a drag effect. However, one of the results of the 1910 paper was that Stoke’s law for the drag on a small droplet fails when the droplets are “too small.”. In the 1913 paper, I thin only the weight of the droplet $mg$ appears in the expressions.

In any case, the “standard value” $g=9.81\,\rm m/s^2$ is a part-per-$10^4$ precision. It is straightforward to do better in a lab if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I still don't see how reproduce Millikan's values of $e_n$ exactly.

Comment: You don't actually say in your question what you dislike about you computation — at least not in a way that I can understand without squinting at your columns of numbers.  I notice you have non-integer $n$, but you do seem to have integer-ish multiples of $n\approx 1.15$. Are you looking for this 15% correction? Are you worried about a linearity issue that I can't tell at a glance? I also vaguely recall that, in at least one early paper, Millikan used an incorrect value for the viscosity of air or some other parameter.

Comment: My point is plain simple, that I think it should be possible to recalculate the value of $e_n$ from the data provided in the paper and get exactly the same numbers as Millikan. Since I didn't get the exact numbers (see my original post), I guess, that I did something wrong (maybe something simple like a typo in the formula).