# Milikan oil drop experiment, were there really drops that picked up only one electron?

Tags: electrostatics, experimental-physics, charge, measurements

There are representations like this:

[image]

The oil droplets can always absorb a multiple of the electrons, ultimately the simplest ratio is relevant. But such representations have even measuring points of nq with n=1 at the very bottom, were there really drops which have taken up only one electron?

Comment: [See also here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/627146/44126). Millikan was able to measure *changes* on the charge of a single drop. For example, one drop’s charge varied from $18\to24\to17\to18$. The differential measurements were much more reliable than the absolute measurements, because many systematic errors cancelled out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below is a paragraph from Millikan's original 1913 paper which you can find online here https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.2.109

It summarizes the results from the 58 drops that he included in the report including number of elementary charges on the drops observed which ranged from 1 to 136. So it looks like the answer to your question is yes, there are really drops which have only one extra electron.

> Table XX. contains a complete summary of the results obtained on
> all of the 58 different drops upon which complete series of observations
> like the above were made during a period of 6o consecutive days. It will
> be seen from this table that these observations represent a 3o-fold variation in $l/a$ (from .016, drop No. 1, to .444, drop No. 58), a 17-fold variation
> in $p$ (from 4.46 cm. , drop No. 56, to 76.27 cm. , drop No. 10), a 12-fold
> variation in $a$ (from $4.69 \times 10^{-5}$ cm. , drop No. 28, to $58.65 \times 10^{-5}$ cm. ,
> drop No. 1) and a variation in the number of free electrons carried by
> the drop from 1 on drop No. 28 to 136 on drop No. 56. The time of fall
> of drop No. 28 was also tested when it was completely discharged, as
> have been the times of many other drops which carried most of the time
> but one electron.